# Is there an automatic way to move questions to Mathoverflow?

Tags: support, mathoverflow

I asked this question

[Lifting isomorphisms between derived categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158138/lifting-isomorphisms-between-derived-categories)

a few days a go, and I now think that it might be more suitable for Mathoverflow.

Is it possible somehow to move this question to this site? Is Mathoverflow part of the stackexchange network?

Comment: In this case I think the question is well-suited for MO.  But general advice to others: wait longer than 3 days before re-posting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. MathOverflow is (was?) part of [StackExchange 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network#StackExchange_1.0) and is run independently of the rest of the network. In particular, moderators cannot migrate to MathOverflow from anywhere else in the network. Just post it on MO (making sure to link both questions to each other).

Comment: Thank you! done.

Comment: I am curious if moderators or some other uses familiar with both sites can nominate some unanswered or unaccepted questions as candidates migrated to MO?

Comment: @Tim: MO is migrating to StackExchange 2.0 soon. When that happens, moderators will be able to freely move questions back and forth, and non-moderators can flag questions they would like migrated.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you know whether there are any plans to merge MathOverflow.com into http://math.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The migration you alluded to in your 2012 comment happened long ago, so your answer here isn't on-target any longer. But it still comes up prominently in searches. It might be worth amending it, or pointing to a newer thread, like here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23091/can-we-move-an-unanswered-question-to-mathoverflow.